# Creating a task that runs at incorrect login credentials

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to set up a personalized security option on my computer to take a picture using the webcam whenever someone tries to log onto my computer using an incorrect password.
I've set up the task in the task scheduler, and I can get it to pass, but then the problem begins.
When the task passes, it triggers like a million times and keeps going until I disable the task.

Does anybody know why it might be doing that and how to make it not?

EDIT:
I'm not an expert at the task scheduler, but I think this is the
[Event log and trigger set](http://ilovealeu.deviantart.com/art/Don-t-mind-this-461010382?ga_submit_new=10%253A1402847621).

EDIT:
I fixed the recursive running issue by inserting the following into the batch file that was triggered:

```
<code>schtasks /change /tn "\Event Viewer Tasks\Task_Name" /DISABLE</code>
```

and checking the "run with highest privileges" box in the settings. This disables the task once it's been run, effectively stopping recursion.

However, now the program no longer runs at incorrect password until after I've logged in, defeating the purpose.

Comment: share the event logs and trigger set

Comment: I like the idea of this...

Comment: I've added a link to what I think pulsarjune is asking for to the original post.

Comment: Try changing "/change" to "/end" and remove "/disable" from your bat file line where you stop the recursion.

Comment: Big Chris: Unfortunately, I tried that first. It didn't stop the recursion; in fact, it only stopped a single instance of the program.

Comment: where does the recursion come from? what is the name of your batch file? It's not ´schtasks.bat´ or is it?